# javascript reduce to desire array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array

```
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", grade:'98'},
{id:2, name:"jack", grade:'96'}
{id:3, name:"jack", grade:'80'}
{id:4, name:"jack", grade:'76'}
{id:5, name:"jack", grade:'78'}
{id:6, name:"marry", grade:'90'},
{id:7, name:"marry", grade:'91'},
{id:8, name:"marry", grade:'96'},
{id:9, name:"marry", grade:'95'},
{id:10, name:"marry", grade:'82'},
{id:11, name:"paul", grade:'87'},
{id:12, name:"paul", grade:'98'},
{id:13, name:"paul", grade:'95'},
{id:14, name:"paul", grade:'93'},
{id:15, name:"paul", grade:'75'},
]
```

so I want to design a drop down on react,  with name in the left and a drop down component in the right with grade, I am stuck in when name is jack how in the dropdown only display grade for jack in the dropdown but not someone else's grade. so which basically when name is jack, I need to create a new array like `[98,96,80,76,78]`, and when name is marry, grade array is `[90,91,96,95,82]`, and how to find a way to iterate through each name, I try to use `.map()` but not sure of it.

Answer (score 3):

you can use filter to get the list of object and use map to get the grade like this

```js
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", grade:'98'},
{id:2, name:"jack", grade:'96'},
{id:3, name:"jack", grade:'80'},
{id:4, name:"jack", grade:'76'},
{id:5, name:"jack", grade:'78'},
{id:6, name:"marry", grade:'90'},
{id:7, name:"marry", grade:'91'},
{id:8, name:"marry", grade:'96'},
{id:9, name:"marry", grade:'95'},
{id:10, name:"marry", grade:'82'},
{id:11, name:"paul", grade:'87'},
{id:12, name:"paul", grade:'98'},
{id:13, name:"paul", grade:'95'},
{id:14, name:"paul", grade:'93'},
{id:15, name:"paul", grade:'75'},
];

const getGrade = name => List.filter(val => val.name === name).map(info => info.grade);

console.log('jack',getGrade('jack'));
console.log('paul',getGrade('paul'));
```

Comment: A filter followed by a map should be done in a single reduce so you don't iterate the collection twice List.reduce((results, val) => { if (val.name === name) { results.push(info.grade); } return results;  }, []);

Answer (score 1):

```js
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", grade:'98'},
{id:2, name:"jack", grade:'96'},
{id:3, name:"jack", grade:'80'},
{id:4, name:"jack", grade:'76'},
{id:5, name:"jack", grade:'78'},
{id:6, name:"marry", grade:'90'},
{id:7, name:"marry", grade:'91'},
{id:8, name:"marry", grade:'96'},
{id:9, name:"marry", grade:'95'},
{id:10, name:"marry", grade:'82'},
{id:11, name:"paul", grade:'87'},
{id:12, name:"paul", grade:'98'},
{id:13, name:"paul", grade:'95'},
{id:14, name:"paul", grade:'93'},
{id:15, name:"paul", grade:'75'},
]
const names = {};
List.map(a => {
    if(!names[a.name]) {
        names[a.name] = [];
    }
    names[a.name].push(a.grade);
})
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took it you wanted to reduce the array, not just get the grades for a person. If so:

```
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", grade:'98'},
{id:2, name:"jack", grade:'96'},
{id:3, name:"jack", grade:'80'},
{id:4, name:"jack", grade:'76'},
{id:5, name:"jack", grade:'78'},
{id:6, name:"marry", grade:'90'},
{id:7, name:"marry", grade:'91'},
{id:8, name:"marry", grade:'96'},
{id:9, name:"marry", grade:'95'},
{id:10, name:"marry", grade:'82'},
{id:11, name:"paul", grade:'87'},
{id:12, name:"paul", grade:'98'},
{id:13, name:"paul", grade:'95'},
{id:14, name:"paul", grade:'93'},
{id:15, name:"paul", grade:'75'},
];
const reduced = List.reduce((accum, x) => {
  const f = accum.find(y => y.name === x.name);
  if (f) f.grade.push(x.grade);
  else {
    accum.push({
      name: x.name,
      grade: [x.grade],
    });
  }
  return accum;
}, []);


console.log(reduced);
// [ { name: 'jack', grade: [ '98', '96', '80', '76', '78' ] },
// { name: 'marry', grade: [ '90', '91', '96', '95', '82' ] },
// { name: 'paul', grade: [ '87', '98', '95', '93', '75' ] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create an array and store all students' names there and then using map function, create an array of objects which will give you the desired output.

```js
let list = [
{id:1, name:"jack", grade:'98'},
{id:2, name:"jack", grade:'96'},
{id:3, name:"jack", grade:'80'},
{id:4, name:"jack", grade:'76'},
{id:5, name:"jack", grade:'78'},
{id:6, name:"marry", grade:'90'},
{id:7, name:"marry", grade:'91'},
{id:8, name:"marry", grade:'96'},
{id:9, name:"marry", grade:'95'},
{id:10, name:"marry", grade:'82'},
{id:11, name:"paul", grade:'87'},
{id:12, name:"paul", grade:'98'},
{id:13, name:"paul", grade:'95'},
{id:14, name:"paul", grade:'93'},
{id:15, name:"paul", grade:'75'},
]

let students = [];
let grades = [];
for(let row of list) {
    if(!students.includes(row.name)) students.push(row.name);
}
console.log(students);
students.map(stud => {
    let arr = [], obj={};
    list.map(li => {        
        if(li.name === stud) arr.push(li.grade);
    })
    obj.name = stud;
    obj.grades = arr;
    grades.push(obj);
})
console.log(grades);
```

Answer (score 0):

Build one object with keys as name and values as aggregated grade using `forEach` loop. This way in one iteration, you can gather the data you need.

```js
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", grade:'98'},
{id:2, name:"jack", grade:'96'},
{id:3, name:"jack", grade:'80'},
{id:4, name:"jack", grade:'76'},
{id:5, name:"jack", grade:'78'},
{id:6, name:"marry", grade:'90'},
{id:7, name:"marry", grade:'91'},
{id:8, name:"marry", grade:'96'},
{id:9, name:"marry", grade:'95'},
{id:10, name:"marry", grade:'82'},
{id:11, name:"paul", grade:'87'},
{id:12, name:"paul", grade:'98'},
{id:13, name:"paul", grade:'95'},
{id:14, name:"paul", grade:'93'},
{id:15, name:"paul", grade:'75'},
]

const all = {};
List.forEach(
  ({ name, grade }) => (all[name] = (all[name] ?? []).concat([grade]))
);

console.log(all["jack"]);
console.log(all["paul"]);
```